# Div over canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html

This is my login page I want to place my login-box over canvas now first show canvas and then show the div i want login-box div over this canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' name='viewport'> <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="bootstrap/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> </head> <body class="login-page"> <canvas id="header-canvas" style="background-color:#999"> <header id="header" > </header> </canvas> <div class="login-box" > <div class="login-box-body"> <form action="" method="post" name="login"> <div class="form-group has-feedback "> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username / Email" required name="login_name"/> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span> </div> <div class="form-group has-feedback"> <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="login_pass"required/> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span> </div> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-4"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button> </div> </div> </form> </div> </div> <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script src="plugins/magnificpopup/plugins.js"></script> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Hard to answer without a jsfiddle, link, or some code to look at.

Comment: Please provide code it will be more easy to identify problem

Comment: It's easy. But, you should provide your code first.

Comment: <canvas id="header-canvas" style="background-color:#999"> <header id="header" > </header> </canvas>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following way you can put put over canvas using `position:absolute;`

```css
#header-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.login-box {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="header-canvas" style="background-color:#999"> <header id="header" > </header> </canvas>

<div class="login-box" > <div class="login-box-body">
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback ">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username / Email" required name="login_name"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span> 
 </div> 
  <div class="form-group has-feedback"> 
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" name="login_pass"required/> 
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span> 
  </div> 
  <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-4"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button> </div> 
</div> 
</form> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6m6vn8g4/)**